# Override CSS property

Tags: css

I have 2 file `theme.css` and `main.css`

**theme.css**

```
.table td {
           border-top: 1px solid #e8edf1;
           vertical-align: top;
           padding: 5px 5px !important;
           color: #576475;
           font-size: 11px;
}
```

**main.css**

```
.table td {
            padding: 1px 2px;
 }
```

I want to override property of `td` via `main.css` by including `main.css` after `theme.css`.

But final output takes property of `theme.css` .

PS: I want to override only padding property.

Comment: add `padding: 1px 2px !important;`

Comment: Not directly related to the problem, but I'd expect a main.css to come before theme.css, because the first sounds more generic and a theme is something easily replaceable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the first CSS rules has `!important` applied, the only way to override it is using another `!important` rule:

```
.table td {
    padding: 1px 2px !important;
}
```

If you can, remove the `!important` keyword from all your CSS. There's better ways of defining the order.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of specificty, `!important` wins every time.

You should really avoid using `!important` and use specifity to your advantage. Ordering CSS files is one way to do it, ordering your rules is another.

For more on specificity: [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

So, in your case, you should remove the `!important` flag from your `theme.css` file, and that would solve it.

Answer (score 0):

@Abhishek Please check following code with example of two different tables as per your requirement.

```css
table td {
           border-top: 1px solid #e8edf1;
           vertical-align: top;
           padding: 5px 5px !important;
           color: #576475;
           font-size: 11px;
}

table.custom_table td{
  padding: 1px 2px !important;
 }
```

```html
<table>
        <tr>  
            <td>fdhf</td>
             <td>dfdfdf</td>
          </tr>
              
  
</table>
<table class="custom_table">
        <tr>  
            <td>fdhf</td>
             <td>dfdfdf</td>
          </tr>
              
  
</table>
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. What did you change? Why does it solve the problem?